# Work with Ruby 1.9 String as a stream of bytes, rather than an encoded string

Tags: ruby, string

Is it possible to get the old Ruby 1.8 behavior on a string, and work with it as a stream of bytes rather than an encoded string?

In particular, I'm trying to get a few bytes combined with a Unicode-encoded string, so:

```
\xFF\x00\x01#{Unicode encoded string}
```

However, if I try to do that, it's also trying to encode \xFF\x00\x01 which won't work.

**Code**

What I'm trying to do in irb:

```
"#{[4278190080].pack("V").force_encoding("BINARY")}\xFF".force_encoding("BINARY")
```

This is giving me:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
        from (irb):41
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I also tried with ASCII-8BIT with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `string = string.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")` to any string that you want to treat as a plain old series of bytes.  Then you should be able to add the two strings together.

I think `.force_encoding("BINARY")` might work too.

Comment: That didn't quite seem to work. I modified the post with the actual code I'm trying to test with.

Comment: Please post a full stack trace.  I suspect your error is coming from withing Zlib::crc32 but I cannot tell.  If it is coming from within Zlib then you should ask a new question about how to fix Zlib.

Comment: Your edit totally changes the nature of the question. I thought this was a question about adding two strings and now it turns out you are calling some (third-party?) library.

Comment: I had thought about that, but the stack trace doesn't indicate that. Zlib::crc32 is returning an integer which I'm using Array.pack on to pack into the 4 bytes that represent it, so that shouldn't be causing any issues.

Comment: Then you should break you code out onto different lines and identify which line is throwing the exception.  You should use `inspect` to see the inputs to the line that is throwing the exception and write some simple example code that reproduces the problem without calling a library.

Comment: Even without zlib (just using an integer), the issue persists. What I posted is from irb, so that is the single line of code that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're interpolating string literal is in UTF-8 by default. I think the `Encoding::CompatibilityError` is caused by interpolating a BINARY encoded string within a UTF-8 string.

Try just concatenating strings with compatible encodings, eg:

```
irb> s = [4278190080].pack("V") + "\xFF".force_encoding("BINARY")
=> "\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF"
irb>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
irb> s=[4278190080].pack("V") + [0xFF].pack("C")
=> "\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF"
irb> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```